# Challenge: Run script as admin with only HDD access

Tags: windows, security, filesystems, registry

So I have a challenge at college to cause minor havoc with a computer much like this one:
https://superuser.com/questions/275894/how-to-mess-up-a-pc-running-windows-7

However the computer will have a password and bios password.

My plan is to plug the hard drive into another computer and try to run scripts.

Putting files in startup is a good start but it would be good to have admin privileges.

The PC is running Windows 10

Any thoughts?

Comment: so why don't you post your question on superuser?

Comment: oh that is a fair point sorry

Answer (score 0):

Damage: Registry edits (Doesn't need admin)

Start Up Application

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "stringname" /d "startup task location" /f
```

Control: Write a program that listens for packets from a client to run on pc using Winsock

Here's one I wrote:
https://github.com/Firestarthirty/BotNet/tree/master